Cargar nueva pestaña en navegador en ASP.NET WEB FORM
mucho gusto en poderlos saludar.
Estoy estudiando ASP.NET Webform c# y estoy haciendo como ejercicio un pequeño proyecto de un almacen de 5 formularios (aspx), Formularios de Clientes, Empleados, Producto, Login y Pannel Principal.
El detalle es que cuando estoy en el pannel principal y le doy click al boton que me envia al formulario (por ejemplo Clientes) me lo carga en la misma pagina... quisiera que cuando le de click me abra el formulario en otra pestaña del navegador.
Muchisimas gracias por su amable y profesional ayuda.

Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! cambia el target del href a blank para que se abra en una nueva pagina.. pero eso no suena muy logico...

Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Tu pregunta es un poco confusa, pero me parece que lo que buscas es el atributo target="_blank" a la hora de crear el link en el HTML.
Ejemplo de esto: <a href="https://www.example.com" target="_blank">Visit Example.com</a>
Espero te sea de ayuda.
Saludos.
